# Does Google backup the files in a Google Script App?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to know and gather more information about whether Google Script Apps are backed up and where they are backed up if possible.

Comment: This is not a good question for Stack Overflow.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  A good question should have code, and an explanation of what you have tried, and what is not working.  You could try asking the question in the Apps Script Community:  [Link to Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Answer (score 1):

There is a *See revision history* item available under the File menu.  This has saved edits and could be considered a sort of backup.